# How to call/use MRI Ruby from Java?

Tags: java, c, ruby, jruby

I want to call Ruby methods from a Java environment. I have tried these four solutions:

1. **Use JRuby**. This would be excellent because it runs everything in the Java virtual machine. However I have experienced some critical (unacceptable) performance issues:

   - JRuby does currently not work with my C extensions.
   - Fork calls from Ruby, do not behave stable when running in the Java virtual machine.
   - The code runs slower in JRuby than in MRI Ruby.
2. **Use ROR**. Bypass Java all together by providing webservices via Ruby on Rails. This works but breaks the companies IT policy of using Java webservices only, it also forces either the IT department (Java and webservice developers) or the R&D department (Ruby and C developers) to work outside there domain.
3. **Use Java system calls**. We can call stand alone Ruby programs with Java system calls and parse input and output data via XML files. This works, but the overhead of starting new processes and handling XML files is a performance issue.
4. **Use RJB**. Ruby Java Bridge allows me to call Java from Ruby, but that is the reverse of what I need.

Is there a method to call MRI Ruby from Java, without any of the above described issues?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what are you doing that JRuby is slower than MRI? JRuby has (much) higher latency than MRI, but its throughput should be significantly higher. Otherwise, the JRuby *will* consider that a bug.

Comment: A colleague of mine looked into the JRuby solution about a year ago (201103), experiencing the three issues that I have described. At this time I unfortunately don't have the details on why JRuby seemed to run slower with our software anymore. The main issue was that we could not get the C extensions including the gnu scientific library to work. The ability to code critical parts in C is our main way of getting performance, so not being able to do that was a major issue for us, but maybe JRuby has improved since.

Comment: Ah, yes, if you are depending on C, that will be an issue. JNI *is* awfully slow, mainly due to the complexities of ensuring memory and type safety while at the same time allowing C idioms like pointer arithmetic. Did you check for numerical libraries for Java? The HotSpot JVM is *really* really incredibly mind-boggingly awesome these days, especially in Java 7. I wouldn't be surprised if it could compete with or even beat C.

Answer (score 1):

You could make #3 more efficient by

- not starting processes, instead use a long-running daemon process
- not communicating via files but via pipes
- using something more efficient than XML, like Protocol Buffers

But in general, I don't see any option you missed. Sorry.